# magento 1.9.0.1 no order mails with store email, what could cause this?

Tags: email, ce-1.9.0.1, sales-order

when placing an order, the customer does receive the order confirmation. also the e-mail copy is received at the correct address (all configured in sale emails)... but for some reason i don not receive the order confirmation (nor the invoice) at the addresses configured.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: Can you confirm emails are activated at System -> Configuration -> Sales Emails?

Comment: yes, they are all set to yes. Maybe i have a wrong understanding from how this works? Very well possible :-)... for example the top one, orders: 

in order confirmation email: i have chosen the sales contact

I have kept the templates set to the default ones for now

In send email copy to: i have set an emailaddress for the business that sends the order

In last field i selected BCC

Did i do something wrong? Should i also type my store email in the "email copy to:" field maybe?? My understanding was that for that one the order confirmation email field was used...

Comment: if you want to receive a copy to your store-email you definitely have to put that email in the "email copy to:" field behind the "emailaddress for the business that sends the order" you mentioned.

Comment: so it was a misunderstanding from my side that this was automatically handled just by selecting the contact in the 2nd field from top

Comment: yeah the second one is ONLY from which email that email should be sent!

Comment: You were very helpful in helping me understand this. I know this thread is not for thank you responses, but...Thank you!

Comment: your welcome. i put it as an answer so people see its fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to receive a copy to your store-email you definitely have to put that email in the "email copy to:" field.